# Array sorting in MIPS

Tags: arrays, sorting, mips

So I am working on an assignment to sort an array in MIPS.  The data to sort is given in a separate .asm file as follows:

```
.data
.word 3
.word 40
.word 30
.word 70
.text
```

I decided to use bubble sort.  I am fairly certain that my algorithm is sound, and it appears to sort the data correctly.  The fun thing about this project is that the values we sort will be played as MIDI notes as a means of testing the program (so, naturally, the notes should play in ascending order).  This is working pretty well when I test my code, however, I'm hearing a few strange beats at the end of the MIDI notes.  I stepped through my code and discovered that, at the end, $t1 (the value I use to compare to my loop iterator for completeness) holds a value of 7, when I expected it to hold a value of three.  I assign $t1 as 0($t2), $t2 is 0x10010000 which I assume is still the base address of my array.  The base address of the array should hold 3, shouldn't it?

I'm a little confused about why $t1 is 7 at all... any advice?  I have included all of my code below.

```
#ec2.asm
.include "ec2_data.asm" #must be in the same directory as ec2.asm

#ec2_data.asm:  puts some values in the "data segment"
#the first value is the number of values to sort (n)
#the remaining n word values are the data to sort
#the values will be stored in memory as word values starting 
#   address 0x10010000


j main

#$t2 is hasChanged
#$t3 is itemCount
#$t4 is i, our iterator in the for loop
#$t5 is array[i] (temp)
#$t6 is array[i+1] (temp)

while_label:
beq $t2, $zero, done_sorting        #checks to see if the previous iteration switched any values.  If not, we are done.
addi $t2, $zero, 0          #initialize hasChanged to 0
addi $t3, $t3, -1           #decrement itemCount by -1  
addi, $t0, $t0, 4           #add 4 to the array offset
addi, $t4, $zero, 0         #set our for loop iterator to 0

for_label:
lw $t5, 0($t0)              #set a temp value equal to array[i]
lw $t6, 4($t0)              #set a temp value equal to array[i+1]

beq $t4, $t3, while_label       #for loop:  if i = itemcount, we have incremented all the way through our for loop
bge $t6, $t5, skip_swap         #if array[i+1] is greater than or equal to array[i], we don't need to swap these values
#swap
sw $t6, 0($t0)              #set array[i] equal to array[i+1]
sw $t5, 4($t0)              #set array[i+1] equal to the temp value
addi $t2, $t2, 1            #set hasChanged to 1 to indicate that a swap has been made
skip_swap:
addi, $t4, $t4, 1           #increment i by 1 (for loop iterator)
j for_label             #keep the for loop going!


main:

#read values
addi $t0, $zero, 0x10010000         #sets $t0 to be the base address of the array
addi $t2, $zero, 1
lw $t3, 0($t0)              #stores n in $t3

j while_label

done_sorting:               

# adapted from MIDI example

#duration 25 ms
#instrument (whichever)
#volume 64

addi $v0, $zero, 33         # midi out synchronous
addi $t2, $zero, 0x10010000     # address of original array (which should by now be sorted)
addi $a1, $zero, 250        # duration (ms)
addi $a2, $zero, 1          # instrument
addi $a3, $zero, 64         # volume 
addi $t0, $zero, 0          # counter
lw $t1, 0($t2)          # end of the loop (should be n)
addi $t1, $t1, 4        # adds four to the array offset in $t1
lw $a0, 0($t2)          # stores the first sorted value ( 4($t1) ) in $a0

midi_loop:
    beq $t0, $t1, done
    addi $t2, $t2, 4
    lw $a0, 0($t2)
    syscall 

    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    j midi_loop


done:

#addi $v0, $zero, 10    # syscall for exit
#syscall                # clean exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO I really shouldn't have asked this question without giving my code another once-over.  The errors were extremely simple.  This appears to work.

```
#ec2.asm
.include "ec2_data.asm" #must be in the same directory as ec2.asm

#ec2_data.asm:  puts some values in the "data segment"
#the first value is the number of values to sort (n)
#the remaining n word values are the data to sort
#the values will be stored in memory as word values starting 
#   address 0x10010000


j main

#$t2 is hasChanged
#$t3 is itemCount
#$t4 is i, our iterator in the for loop
#$t5 is array[i] (temp)
#$t6 is array[i+1] (temp)

while_label:
beq $t2, $zero, done_sorting        #checks to see if the previous iteration switched any values.  If not, we are done.
addi $t2, $zero, 0          #initialize hasChanged to 0
addi $t3, $t3, -1           #decrement itemCount by -1  WHY
addi, $t0, $zero, 0x10010000        #add 4 to the array offset
addi, $t4, $zero, 0         #set our for loop iterator to 0

for_label:
addi, $t0, $t0, 4
lw $t5, 0($t0)              #set a temp value equal to array[i]
lw $t6, 4($t0)              #set a temp value equal to array[i+1]

beq $t4, $t3, while_label       #for loop:  if i = itemcount, we have incremented all the way through our for loop
bge $t6, $t5, skip_swap         #if array[i+1] is greater than or equal to array[i], we don't need to swap these values
#swap
sw $t6, 0($t0)              #set array[i] equal to array[i+1]
sw $t5, 4($t0)              #set array[i+1] equal to the temp value
addi $t2, $t2, 1            #set hasChanged to 1 to indicate that a swap has been made
skip_swap:
addi, $t4, $t4, 1           #increment i by 1 (for loop iterator)
j for_label             #keep the for loop going!


main:

#read values
addi $t0, $zero, 0x10010000         #sets $t0 to be the base address of the array
addi $t2, $zero, 1
lw $t3, 0($t0)              #stores n in $t3

j while_label

done_sorting:               

# adapted from MIDI example

#duration 25 ms
#instrument (whichever)
#volume 64

addi $v0, $zero, 33         # midi out synchronous
addi $t2, $zero, 0x10010000     # address of original array (which should by now be sorted)
addi $a1, $zero, 250        # duration (ms)
addi $a2, $zero, 1          # instrument
addi $a3, $zero, 64         # volume 
addi $t0, $zero, 0          # counter
lw $t1, 0($t2)          # end of the loop (should be n)
lw $a0, 0($t2)          # stores the first sorted value ( 4($t1) ) in $a0

midi_loop:
    beq $t0, $t1, done
    addi $t2, $t2, 4
    lw $a0, 0($t2)
    syscall 

    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    j midi_loop


    done:
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sorting algorithm is quite broken.  You haven't noticed that because it happens to get the right answer with your test data.  It will produce the wrong answer with other test data (e.g. I believe your algorithm will sort 70, 40, 30 to 40, 30, 70).

But your question was about why `$t1` ends up with value `7`.  The answer is simple.  You wrote this:

```
addi $t2, $zero, 0x10010000     # address of original array (which should by now be sorted)
addi $a1, $zero, 250        # duration (ms)
addi $a2, $zero, 1          # instrument
addi $a3, $zero, 64         # volume 
addi $t0, $zero, 0          # counter
lw $t1, 0($t2)          # end of the loop (should be n)
addi $t1, $t1, 4        # adds four to the array offset in $t1
```

We can see that you set `$t2` to 0 + 0x10010000 = 0x10010000.  Then you load the word at `0($t2)` (= 0x10010000) into `$t1`.  The word at 0x10010000 is 3, so at that point `$t1` is 3.  Then you add 4 to `$t1`, storing the result in `$t1`.  At that point `$t1` is 7.  You never modify `$t1` after that.

Comment: Haha yes, sorry, I should have edited my post :P  I found that right after I asked the question and felt silly...  Thank you for your response!  I'll work on correcting my sorting algorithm as well.